# Assets not uploading to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

This is my new s3 account and new project.

Everything is fine with `assets:precompile`, all assets are precompiled and stored in `public/assets`.

But this assets are no either uploading or syncing to s3.

Here my fog initializer

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'AWS_KEY',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'AWS_SECRET'
  }

  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'

  config.fog_public = false
end
```

I have added 'fog' gem in gemfile.

Interesting thing is that, I am able to upload images from development to s3, but in production it is giving `Permission denied` to `/public/uploads/tmp`. This shouldn't happen right!!

Please help me in syncing my assets to s3.

Comment: And why you expect them to be uploaded to s3? You're mentioning CarrierWave which is used for file upload, not assets.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. And i figured out the issue. I have to use 'asset_sync' gem and its configuration to upload to s3. Now its solved.

Comment: Please consider closing/removing this question then.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user your httpd is running as

```
ps aux | grep [thehttpd]
```

Then make sure to change ownership

```
chown [theuser] /public/uploads/tmp
```

and give write permissions to /public/uploads/tmp to that user

```
chmod 755 /public/uploads/tmp
```

Don't forget to replace [thehttpd] and [theuser] with your values

Comment: I din't know that I have to use 'assest_sync' to sync to s3. After adding it I solved problem.